# Filtering in pandas - how to apply a custom method (lambda)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where one of the columns contains an string which contains words  delimited by comma.

```
>>> df['column1']
# ....
996                  str1, str2, str3
997                  str4, str5, str7
998                  str8, str9, str10
# ...........
```

I need to treat the content of that column as an array of string so I can do this:

```
 [
  # ..... 
  & (df['column1'].isin('str2')) # should return the row #996
  # ....
 ]
```

I tried this but it hasn't panned out, of course:

```
 [
  # ..... 
  & (df['column1'].split(',').isin('str2'))
  # ....
 ]
```

How can I do that? Or rather how can I use a method (lambda) to modify the content of the column before filtering?

UPDATE1:

This is a part of my code:

```
for x in pd.read_csv.....
      df_item = x

      if filter1:
        df_item = df_item[(df_item['column1'] == filter1)]

      if filter2:
        df_item = df_item[(df_item['column2'].isin(subjects))]

      # .....
```

How can I apply `df['column2'].apply(lambda x: 'str2' in x.split(','))` to

```
  if filter2:
    df_item = df_item[(df_item['column2'].isin(subjects))]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isin` checks whether the value from the series is in the iterable (in your case `'str2'` ) . Not whether `str2` is contained in your series' value.

If your series contains strings, then a method to get what you want would be to use `.str.contains()` to check whether the string contains `str2` . Example -

```
df['column1'].str.contains('str2')
```

---

If you must split the contents use `','`  (that is if `str2` can be a substring of any of the other strings) . You can use `Series.apply` . Example -

```
df['column1'].apply(lambda x: 'str2' in x.split(','))
```

To apply this, simply use this to filter the DataFrame. Example -

```
if <somefilter>:
    df_item = df_item[df_item['column2'].apply(lambda x: 'str2' in x.split(','))]
```

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp if your data looks like the data in your question, make sure you split by ', ' instead of ',' (there's an extra space).

Comment: ops, one more thing. What if the key to filter for (`str2`) is an array itself? For example: `.....apply(lambda x: ['str2', 'str4'] in x.split(','))]`? That won't work, but actually that's what I need -- the filter should be an array. And if any element from ['str2', 'str4'] contains in x.split(',') then that's True condition.

Comment: You can use `any()` or set intersection. Like - `any(y in x.split(',') for y in ['str2', 'str4'])` . But that should be very slow. Another method - `len({'str2', 'str4'} & set(x.split(,')) > 0` .

Comment: sorry, `len({'str2', 'str4'} & set(x.split(,')) > 0` doesn't work for me because `'str2', 'str4'` is in a variable `filter1 = ['str2', 'str4']`. And `len({filter1} & ...` doesn't work.

Comment: If it's in a variable , you have two options , either define them with { and } . Or use set() as set(filter)