# pd.DataFrame with scalar values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to delete some rows from a CSV file by saving a new CSV after a validation process. I wrote the code below but it causes an error.

```
with open(path_to_read_csv_file, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        # if validation(line[specific_column]):
            try:
                df = pd.DataFrame(line)
                df.to_csv(path_to_save_csv_file)

            except Exception as e:
                print('Something Happend!')
                print(e)
                continue
```

Error:

```
Something Happend!
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I've also tried to add an index value by `df = pd.DataFrame(line, index=[0])`, but it only stores the first line with an additional empty column at the beginning. How can solve this?

Another version with `line` works but I can not reach a specific key value at each line:

```
inFile = open(path_to_read_csv_file, 'r')
outFile = open(path_to_save_csv_file, 'w')

for line in inFile:
    try:
        print('Analysing:', line)

        # HERE, how can I get the specific column value? I used to use line[specific_column] in the last version
        if validation(line[specific_column]):
            outFile.write(line)
        else:
            continue

    except Exception as e:
        print('Something Happend!')
        print(e)
        continue

outFile.close()
inFile.close()
```

Comment: Just do `pd.read_csv(path_to_read_csv_file)`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi) should help you. Basically, you cannot create a DataFrame from scalar-values only. They have to be wrapped in eg. a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `pd.DataFrame` expects you to tell how the data that you have provided has to be indexed as well. This is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

The function `csv.DictReader` uses

> the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames.

For more information, refer to the csv [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Hence, each `line` that is parsed by the `csv_reader` is a dictionary where the keys are the CSV header and the values are each the row in the particular line.

So for example, if my CSV is:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
1,2,3
11,11,33
```

Then in the first iteration, the `line` object would be:

```
{'Header1': '1', 'Header2': '2', 'Header3': '3'}
```

Now when you supply this to `pd.DataFrame`, you need to specify what the data is and what the headers/indices are. In this case, the data is `['1', '2', '3']` and the headers/indices are `['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']`. These can be extracted by the calls `line.values()` and `line.keys()` respectively.

This is the change I have made.

```
with open(path_to_read_csv_file, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        try:
            # validation ...
            df = pd.DataFrame(line.values(), line.keys())
            df.to_csv(path_to_save_csv_file)

        except Exception as e:
            print('Something Happend!')
            print(e)
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But these codes only stores the last line. I've just to use line and it works but I can not reach a specific key value at each line. Please see the edited version.

Comment: Can you clarify with an example what exactly you are trying to achieve? Like what would be an input to your program and what would you expect as output?

Comment: I have a large csv file of reviews:
id, name, comment, ...
2302734, David, This is a very nice restaurant, ...
...

And I want to filter some and store the new version.
main.csv ---> edited.csv

Comment: Can you update your question to something that is more indicative of what you are trying to achieve i.e. read a csv, filter the entries and then save it. Then I can edit my answer to let you know how to do that. By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968747/filtering-in-pandas-how-to-apply-a-custom-method-lambda) may help you.